# polynomial with integer coefficient

Tags: polynomials

Suppose $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficient. If there exist $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=f(d)=5$ then there does not exist $k$ such that $f(k)=8$. Prove.

We consider $Q(x)= f(x)-5$. Then $Q(x)$ has 4 distinct roots. According to the problem given, $Q(k)=3$. Hence $(k-a)(k-b)(k-c)(k-d)r(k)=3$. Hence we can not find any contradiction!

Comment: $(k-a)(k-b)(k-c)(k-d)$ is a product of four _distinct_ integers. Can that divide $3$?

Comment: @lulu Nice find, with such descriptive title...

Comment: @NormalHuman I know, right?  It caught my eye when it was posted before...odd that they match so exactly.  I mean, the argument involved is quite general, depending only on the fact that $8-5$ is a prime. The problem in this form must appear somewhere else, newspaper challenge or some such.